# Call derived class appropriately

Tags: c++, list, polymorphism

I have a class `order` and two derived classes: `single_order` and `repeated_order`.

```
struct order{
string desc;
};
```

```
struct single_order : public order{
datetime dt;
};
```

```
struct repeated_order : public order{
datetime dt1;
datetime dt2;
};
```

I have a `list<order*> ll` that can contain `single_order` and `repeated_order` and two methods:

```
bool is_expired(single_order &el){
   if(today>el.dt){
      //do something
   }
}
```

```
bool is_expired(repeated_order &el){
   if(today>el.dt1){
      //do something
   }
   if(today>el.dt2){
      //do something else
   }
}
```

I would like to iterate over `ll` and call the most appropriate method in each case. (the parameter of the two functions may also be other than a reference)

How to do that?

Comment: With polymorphism, and a single function that takes a reference or pointer to the base class.

Comment: The potential code smell here is *"two methods:"* - methods of *what* ? The *list* ? The concept of `bool is_expired()` seems an *ideal* candidate for a virtual method of a polymorphic hierarchy. In other words, a pure method of `order`,  of which `single_order` and `repeated_order` both derive and implement. You'll have two methods, but placed where they belong: the object on which they're reporting.

Comment: As C++ exists now, method dispatch occurs only on the target object; the dispatched function has to be a virtual member function of the polymorphic object.  There are proposals for "multimethods" which allow virtual dispatch on every function argument, not only the target object. (i.e. `*this`).  https://www.stroustrup.com/multimethods.pdf  If that sort of proposal is ever accepted, OP's code would "just work" as structured (it would probably be necessary to mark the functions as multimethods, but they wouldn't have to move into the polymorphic object).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You knew to tag polymorphism, but you seem to be struggling with the concept.
Here's some code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base {
 public:
  Base() = default;
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual void do_foo() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Base {
 public:
  Bar() = default;
  void do_foo() override { std::cout << "From Bar\n"; }
};

class Baz : public Base {
 public:
  Baz() = default;
  void do_foo() override { std::cout << "From BAZ\n"; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v;

  v.emplace_back(new Bar());
  v.emplace_back(new Baz());

  for (const auto& i : v) {
    i->do_foo();
  }
}
```

You can see that in `Base`, there is a pure virtual function, `virtual do_foo() = 0;` This means a couple things. `Base` is a pure virtual class and you cannot declare `Base` objects, only pointers or references to `Base`. In order to have a concrete class, or one that you can create objects of, you need to override those pure virtual functions.

You have a function that you want to be able to call on both derived types. This is a perfect example of how polymorphism can make your life easier. You can see that each derived class overrides the pure virtual function and does its own thing, and I am then able to store both derived types in the vector in my `main()` function, and call the appropriate function on each object.

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
From Bar
From BAZ
```